# function(){}(args) doesn't work in FF?

Tags: javascript

```
function test(json_parameters){console.log(json_parameters);}({"foo":"bar"});
```

Doesn't work in FF, though.. it should. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the function in parens:

```
(function test(json_parameters){console.log(json_parameters);})({"foo":"bar"});
```

Otherwise it will be treated as a function declaration followed by an object literal statement, like this:

```
function test(json_parameters) {
    console.log(json_parameters);
};
({"foo":"bar"});
```

All the major browsers work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put parentheses around the function definition for this to work.

```
(function test(json_parameters){console.log(json_parameters);})({"foo":"bar"});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a valid Javascript statement, per [12.4](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_12.htm#Section_12.4) of the standard: `an ExpressionStatement cannot start with the function keyword because that might make it ambiguous with a FunctionDeclaration`. Since it is not a valid statement, a semicolon is automatically inserted after the `}` sign to make it valid, per [7.9.1](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_7.htm#Section_7.9.1), breaking it into two separate parts, a [function declaration](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_13.htm#Section_13) and an expression statement (which doesn't do anything).

To make it work, you must ensure it does not start with the `function` keyword. The two common ways of doing that are

```
(function test(json_parameters){console.log(json_parameters);})({"foo":"bar"});
```

and

```
(function test(json_parameters){console.log(json_parameters);}({"foo":"bar"}));
```

but anything else should work too, like

```
+function test(json_parameters){console.log(json_parameters);}({"foo":"bar"});
```